# MQTT - how to check port and IP is running in mqtt

Tags: java, mqtt

I am trying to check the given IP and port running or not, if not then I have to return exception to client.

Here is my code,

```
MqttMessage message2 = new MqttMessage();
MQTT mqtt_connect = new MQTT();
mqtt_connect.setHost(Host_Address, Integer.parseInt(port));
String topic = "/call/MQTT_Config";
mqtt_connect.setClientId("MQTT_Config");
mqtt_connect.setWillRetain(false);
mqtt_connect.isWillRetain();
mqtt_connect.setWillTopic(topic);
BlockingConnection m_publisher = mqtt_connect.blockingConnection();
m_publisher.connect();
if(connection establish){ 
    // here how to check the condition 
    do publish  here
}
else{
    return "connection failure";
}
```

Someone tell me the validation in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap up your code in try/catch as follow

```
try{
    MqttMessage message2 = new MqttMessage();
    MQTT mqtt_connect = new MQTT();
    mqtt_connect.setHost(Host_Address, Integer.parseInt(port));
    String topic = "/call/MQTT_Config";
    mqtt_connect.setClientId("MQTT_Config");
    mqtt_connect.setWillRetain(false);
    mqtt_connect.isWillRetain();
    mqtt_connect.setWillTopic(topic);
    BlockingConnection m_publisher = mqtt_connect.blockingConnection();
    m_publisher.connect();

}
catch(Exception e){
    add message for connection not established
}
```